# Easier Way To Narrate Over Paused Frame?

Tags: video-editor, audio, windows-movie-maker

In order to add commentary to a fast moving video I've been pausing the frame by taking a snapshot, saving to a file, recording narration, saving to a file, then manually adjusting the snapshot time. But the process feels clumsy in Windows Movie Maker. That software is also no longer supported by Microsoft.

Ideally I'd prefer to use a simple GUI editor like Movie Maker (ideally with keyboard shortcuts and/or voice control) since I don't have a lot of free time to master an advanced tool. Though if more involved tools are the only way to streamline the process then please share your experience.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to upgrade to a slightly more serious editing suite? Because if you do, there will be a swarm of people waiting to tell you an easy and effective way to do what you're asking.

Comment: In that case, which suite would you recommend and how would I do it with that tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple Video editing suite called [**Camtasia**](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html).It is not free but you can try out the trial,If you like it you can purchase it.
It has an **"Extend Frame"** feature (also available in 7th version) that will allow you to extend a particular frame of video on the timeline as long as you want so that audio narration can continue.

*That should achieve the same effect as pausing the video during recording, as in either case you will end up with a static image on the screen while the audio finishes playing out.*

Then come in afterwards, play this pre-recorded screen video back... and lay down audio on top ***WHILE** being able to hit pause on the video, and continue talking, to whichever points in the video require more explanation.You can just simply check it out.